# use same assembly name as namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

I'm working on a wpf application and I'd like to use namespaces with the pattern "[company].[application].[solutionfolder].$(MSBuildProjectName)"
When I use the same pattern for namespace and assembly, xaml-compiler fails with MC3050 "cannot find type ...".

When I leave assemblyname in VS untouched (only $(MSBuildProjectName) ) all works fine, no errors and application works as expected.

Is there a way to use desired assembly-name-pattern and tell xaml-compiler where to find the needed classes?

With extended assembly name I tried any hint I could find about namespace problems.
Remove all bin/* and obj/*, change runtime target, add namespace for classes in same assembly, ...

I run out of ideas.

At last I tried to leave RootNamespace untouched and use extended assembly names, but MC3050 occurred anyway.

The only way (I found) was, leaving assembly name untouched.